# Adding bits, simpler

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

Considering that two bitsets are provided in the form of strings, `char a[]` and `char b[]`, as in the code below. And the task of add that bitsets is given. I take it and wrote the following to sum the two bitsets:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int carry = 0;
char result(char r, int c) {
    char R = '0';
    if (carry) {
        if (c) {
            R = '0';
            carry = 1;
        } else {
            R = r == '0' ? '1' : '0';
            carry = R == '0' ? 1 : 0;
        }
    } else {
        if (c) {
            R = '0';
            carry = 1;
        } else {
            R = r;
            carry = 0;
        }
    }
    return R;
}

char sum(int x, int y) {
    char r = '0';
    if (x ^ y) 
        r = result('1', 0);
    else if (x & y)
        r = result('0', 1);
    else 
        r = result('0', 0);
    return r;
}

int main() { 
    char a[] = "01";
    char b[] = "01";
    char c[] = "00";
    for (int i = strlen(c)-1; i > -1; i--) 
        c[i] = sum(a[i] == '0' ? 0 : 1, b[i] == '0' ? 0 : 1);
    printf("%s\n", c);
}
```

Is it possible to make it simpler?

Comment: i think your question would be better suited for codereview http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Mountain out of a molehill. The code seems obfuscated. It would be clear to add two digits (sources and result adjusted for character value) and pass a `carry` to the next digit left. Then it will work for as many digits as you can wish for (but obviously but not huge). that can be done in a single small loop.

Comment: Are you coming from VHDL/Verilog background by a chance?

Comment: Note that this code is broken; this gives a result of `10` for `11 + 11`.  If it weren't broken, I would say put it on Code Review. But as it stands, it seems appropriate here.

Comment: I think I fixed it, just a matter of changing `R = '0';
                carry = 1;` in the beginning.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'll appreciate an answer a little more verbose.

Comment: Also consider `char c[] = "00";`. And, it is generally a bad idea to modify your code once you post a question. Add an update, or an edit, or a self-answer if you like.

Comment: Didn't understand this part "Also consider char c[] = "00";", may I ask for a brief explanation?

Comment: @KcFnMi-- you are modifying the string `"00"` to contain the result, but this string cannot possibly contain the result of `"11" + "11"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void sum_two_charbitsets(int char_count,char*a,char*b,char*result)
{
    int x,i,carry = 0;
    for(i = char_count-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      x=(a[i]-'0')+(b[i]-'0')+carry;
      result[i]=(x&1)+'0';
      carry=x>>1;   
    } 
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char a[] = "01";
    char b[] = "01";
    char c[] = "00";
    sum_two_charbitsets(2,a,b,c);
    printf("%s\n", c);
}
```

When doing numerical operations, why not use numbers instead of hard to read code full of string comparing and stuff?

In order to use numerical plus operator, I used simple char<->int conversions by subtracting/adding ASCII number of char '0'. Which would work as long as the strings contains only expected characters '0' or '1'.

`number&1` is used to subtract first bit from integer using binary AND operator.

`number>>1` is binary shift operator, which would discard the first bit, moving second bit to the first position => effectively subtracting it. (as long as no other bit is ever set, which should not happen for correct input data)

Comment: Aside from that `void main()` is wrong, this code is broken for the same reason that OP's code is broken. See my comments under the original question.

Comment: Question was broken, now I think is ok.

Comment: When you provide data containment smaller, then possible result, of course you will get overflow. This code won't cause any memory access error in that case, it just wont store the last bit anywhere, which is similar behavior to how adding integers works in C. Using dynamic realloc seems like overkill for this task. Maybe, you may print an error message and force close the program, when carry bit stays set at the end of the loop.

Comment: For `char a[] = "0011";`, `char b[] = "0011";` it returns `0110`. I was expecting `0100`. Is it correct?

Comment: @KcFnMi 3 plus 3 is 4 or 6?